# Why is there a JWT (JSON Web Token) prefix on token? Re: JsonWebTokenError: invalid token

Tags: node.js, jwt, token

Spent a lot of time banging on this JWT error and finally discovered what was causing it, but I don't understand why.

My user.js files (model and routes) generate a token when a user logs in.

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body.email);
        console.log(req.body.password);
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const user = await User.findByCredentials(email, password)
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).send({error: 'Login failed! Check authentication credentials'})
        }
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
        res.send({ user, token })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(400).send(error)
    }
})
```

```
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function() {
    // Generate an auth token for the user
    const user = this
    const token = jwt.sign({
            email: user.email,
            _id: user._id
        }, 
        'badabaloozagoodoo',
        { 
            expiresIn:'1h' 
        }
    )
    console.log('Generating token')
    console.log(token)
    user.tokens = user.tokens.concat({token})
    await user.save()
    return token
}
```

It outputs a token like this:

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImpzbWl0aEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJfaWQiOiI1ZGIyNGRmYzc5NzUyZTYxOGI3OTk1NDYiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzIwMzkxOTcsImV4cCI6MTU3MjA0Mjc5N30.ctdg8vkne1gvD3-Lo6j-T5BQEMVKBoKBsDGddtuQBUE

Then, on a subsequent call for a different route, the following middleware checks to token to make sure the user is authorized.  It kept throwing a **JsonWebTokenError: invalid token** error and I couldn't understand why.  Then I printed the token from the request header to string and noticed that it had a **JWT** prefix for some reason.

> JWTeyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImpzbWl0aEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJfaWQiOiI1ZGIyNGRmYzc5NzUyZTYxOGI3OTk1NDYiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzIwMzkxOTcsImV4cCI6MTU3MjA0Mjc5N30.ctdg8vkne1gvD3-Lo6j-T5BQEMVKBoKBsDGddtuQBUE

So, I added coded to remove the JWT prefix and now the code runs without any error.  Could someone help me understand what is going on?

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const User = require('../../models/user')

const checkAuth = async(req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Check auth")
    try {
        console.log(req.header('Authorization'))
        var token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '')
        token = token.replace('JWT', '')
        console.log(token)
        const data = jwt.verify(token, 'badabaloozagoodoo') 
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: data._id, 'tokens.token': token })
        if (!user) {
            throw new Error('User not found')
        }
        req.user = user
        req.token = token
        next()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Auth failed')
        console.log(error)
        res.status(401).send({ error: 'Not authorized to access this resource.' })
    }
}
module.exports = checkAuth
```

Answer (score 1):

Well. I found my error. I had set up an interceptor to verify the token and it was adding the 'JWT' prefix

```
req = req.clone({headers:req.headers.set('Authorization', 'JWT'+token)}); //passing request 
return next.handle(req)
```